# How do you import a Typescript type definition file whose top level element is a non-exported namespace?

Tags: typescript, namespaces, typescript-definitions

I'm trying to use the [`@types/googlemaps`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlemaps) type definition file.

The code looks like

```
declare namespace google.maps {
    /***** Map *****/
    export class Map extends MVCObject {
        constructor(mapDiv: Element|null, opts?: MapOptions);
        fitBounds(bounds: LatLngBounds|LatLngBoundsLiteral): void;
        ...
        ...
        overlayMapTypes: MVCArray<MapType>;
    }

    export interface MapOptions {
        backgroundColor?: string;
        disableDoubleClickZoom?: boolean;
        draggable?: boolean;
        ...
```

When I try to use this type definition in my project, like so

```
import * as google from 'googlemaps';
```

I get a compile error saying

```
Error:(2, 25) TS2306:File 'C:/Users/CodyB/musicappproj/src/node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

Why does it not consider this types definition file to be a module?
Am I using it wrong ? Is the definition file wrong?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html it must be global declarations instead of  module.. try using `google.maps.Map`.. if that doesnt work try puting `/// <reference types="google" />` on top of your file

Comment: I am also facing this problem when trying to use the types defined at @types/jest for typing the testdouble-jest library.

I tried adding the /// directive as well as all manner of importing in a definition file (testdouble-jest.d.ts), but it seems to always resolve to any. any thoughts how I can proceed?

Comment: Added more details in a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55961831/refer-to-global-declared-namespace-type-in-custom-definition

Answer (score 3):

> Why does it not consider this types definition file to be a module?

**The compiler does not consider this type definition file to be an ECMA6 module because the file lacks a top-level export/import.** Instead, the file nests/hides its exports inside a `namespace` and does not export the namespace. As a result, the namespace becomes part of the global scope, and the file does not become a module.

A file is a module only if it has a top-level import or export. In the following code, both `foo.ts` and `bar.ts` are modules, but `baz.ts` is not, because it lacks a top-level `import` or `export` statement.

```
// foo.ts
console.log('foo');
export {}

// bar.ts
import * as foo from './foo';
console.log('bar');

// baz.ts
console.log('baz');

// index.ts
import * as foo from './foo';
import * as bar from './bar';
import * as baz from './baz'; // File 'c:/dev/temp/baz.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)
```

> Am I using it wrong?

Yes. You are treating the file like it is a module - which it is not. The alternative is to access its members through the global namespace it defines. Here are two approaches:

One is to 'dot into' the namespace like this:

```
const div1 = new HTMLDivElement();
const map1 = new google.maps.Map(div1);
```

Another is to use destructuring like this:

```
const { Map } = google.maps;
const div2 = new HTMLDivElement();
const map2 = new Map(div2);
```

> Is the definition file wrong?

No. It is taking a valid approach albeit one that is arguably more conventional for a browser (e.g. Firefox) application than it is for a NodeJS application.

#### See also:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html