# Refer to global declared namespace type in custom definition

Tags: typescript, types, namespaces, global, libraries

There is a past question on this topic, but no answer was posted:

[How do you import a Typescript type definition file whose top level element is a non-exported namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47826035/how-do-you-import-a-typescript-type-definition-file-whose-top-level-element-is-a?r=SearchResults&s=5|54.8848)

I want to make a type for `testdouble-jest`, but the second argument in its exported function is the global `jest` instance, which is declared in `@types/jest` as a top-level declared namespace:

```js
declare namespace jest {
  mock(): something
  // ...
}
```

EDIT: here are the types: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jest/index.d.ts

How can I refer to this global object in my `test-double.d.ts` declaration? My declaration looks as follows, but with partial success:

```js
/// <reference types="jest" />
// do i actually need the above directive?

declare module "testdouble-jest" {
  import * as td from "testdouble"; // the testdouble stuff works
  export type TestdoubleJest = typeof td & {
    mock: typeof jest.mock;  // this actually appears to work
  };
  function setupTestdoubleJest(
    testdouble: typeof td,
    jest: typeof jest // this just resolves to any
  ): TestdoubleJest;

  export = setupTestdoubleJest;
}
```

If anyone knows how to do this, I would really appreciate it!

EDIT ２： There are some examples on DefinitelyTyped of people either augmenting the ‘jest‘ namespace or using its members (like I did with `jest.mock`), but I can't find one referring to the actual global `jest` object.

- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/39580cb71a89cde61d217d8d418347c58a2f2103/types/jest-json-schema/index.d.ts

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
/// <reference types="jest" />
```

with

```
/// <reference types="@types/jest" />
```

it works for me.